# Generating random even numbers

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate one random integer from 1-10 that is even. 
I wrote this code in R which works, but is there any simpler way to do that? Here is the code:

```
repeat{
 value=sample.int(10,1)
 if(value%%2==0){
   break
 }
}
```

Comment: `2*sample(5,1)`

Comment: less efficient but possibly of interest: `vals <- 1:10; evenvals <- vals[vals %% 2 == 0]; sample(evenvals,1)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
value = 2*sample.int(5,1)
```

Need 30 characters for a full answer in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I had the same problem!

Comment: Ah, yes, `sample.int()`, and I misread the question as asking for `n` numbers.  Will nix my answer.

Comment: Being a stickler, to get integers, you should use `2L * sample.int(5,1)` or `2L * sample(5L, 1)` as muliplication by 2 converts the output to a double: `typeof(2*sample.int(5,1))`.

Comment: @Imo Edit away!  I know nothing about R.  But, I do know how to generate even random numbers....